# Is the singly linked list a palindrome?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have solved this question on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/description/. I convert the nodes into an ArrayList and am wondering if that's cheating? Other than that, how can I optimize this solution:

```
public class PalindromeLinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode node = new ListNode(0);
        node.next = new ListNode(0);
        //node.next.next = new ListNode(1);
        //node.next.next.next = new ListNode(1);

        ArrayList firstHalf = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList secondHalf = new ArrayList();

        int count = 0;

        ListNode counterNode = node;
        while(counterNode != null) {
            count++;
            counterNode = counterNode.next;
        }

        int middle = count/2;
        boolean middleIgnored = count%2 != 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
            firstHalf.add(node.val);
            node = node.next;
        }

        if(middleIgnored) {
            node = node.next;
            System.out.println("middle ignored");
        }

        for(int i = middle + 1; node != null; i++) {
            secondHalf.add(node.val);
            node = node.next;
        }

        Collections.reverse(secondHalf);
        boolean isPalindrome = firstHalf.equals(secondHalf);

        System.out.println("first half: " + firstHalf);
        System.out.println("\nsecond half: " + secondHalf);
        System.out.println("\npalindrome? " + isPalindrome);

    }

}

class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) The problem description on leetcode is short enough to quote here (which, given proper attribution, I consider *fair use*). The way *I* read that question: code `isPalindrome()` and, as a follow-up, *answer*: *can a single solution achieve O(n) time and O(1) space?* (My follow-up: *Without at least temporarily modifying the input?*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeetCode seems to stress *preparation for technical interviews*, I consider it prudent to start sketching *the most simple thing that could possibly do* (I take the liberty to substitute the original last word *work*).
Things I like about your approach:

- conceptually simple & clean:
  comparing first and last half with one reversed

  - relying on runtime support in the environment of choice
    for comparison and reversal

I do *not* consider transforming data to facilitate processing `cheating`, *unless* it explicitly violates part of the task description.
Things I don't like (this far, you saw it coming) about the execution (of said approach):

- missing doc comments

  - e.g. about a known shortcoming:
    using O(n) *additional space* out of convenience, not need
- not defining an explicit predicate `isPalindrome()`
- transforming more than one part of the linked list separately

  - using repeated code (**this may be appropriate in an interview setting, *if* commented** (preferably in the code sketch, too))
- declaring the `List`s for *what they are* (implementing class) instead of *what use they are* (interface)

Giving it a try:

```
/** Checks a home-grown linked list
 * for <i>palindrome</i> using linear additional space.
 * @param node the first node of the list to check, or <code>null</code>
 * @return the order of values in the list
 *  starting from <code>node</code> stays the same when reversed
 */// compare first half to reverse of second half
static boolean isPalindrome(final ListNode node) {
    final List<Integer> items = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

    for (ListNode n = node ; n != null; n = n.next)
        items.add(n.val);

    int count = items.size(),
        middle = count/2; // middle item in neither sublist for odd count
    final List<Integer> tail = items.subList(count-middle, count);
    java.util.Collections.reverse(tail);
    return count < 2 ||
        items.subList(0, middle).equals(tail);
}
/** Builds a node list from values & prints result of isPalindrome() */
static void checkNodeList(String values) {
    ListNode node, n = node = new ListNode(42); // dummy
    for (byte c: values.getBytes())
        n = n.next = new ListNode(c);
    node = node.next; // skip dummy
    System.out.println("palindrome(" + values
              + "): " + isPalindrome(node));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkNodeList("");
    checkNodeList("?");
    checkNodeList("!!");
    checkNodeList("codedoc");
    checkNodeList("codedoC");
    checkNodeList("cOdedoc");
    checkNodeList("Maddam");
    checkNodeList("maddam");
    checkNodeList("madDam");
}
```

`[optimizing] this solution` - I can't make approach or code any clearer.
LeetCode's follow on: *can a single solution achieve O(n) time and O(1) space?*:
I know how to do it *modifying the input*, I doubt it can be done without.
There are many ways to skin cats, thinking how easy it would be using python, I gave turning `ListNode`s into `List`s a try, with loop jamming and use of a sentinel thrown in:

```
/** Checks a home-grown linked <code>List</code>
 * for <i>palindrome</i> using constant additional space.
 * <br/>Temporarily modifies the list starting with <code>node</code>.
 * @param node <code>null</code>, or the first node of the
 *  <code>List</code> to check
 * @return the order of values in the <code>List</code>
 *  starting from <code>node</code> stays the same when reversed
 */
static boolean isPalindrome(final ListNode node) {
    if (null == node)
        return true;
    ListNode
        last,   // traverses list two steps/turn, stops at last node
        middle, // middle of list part already traversed by last
        reversed = null, // reverse of first half
        slow = middle = last = node;
    // jam "counting" and reversal of first half
    for (ListNode next ; ; last = next.next) {
        next = last.next;
        middle = slow.next;
        if (null == next)
            break;
        slow.next = reversed;
        reversed = slow;
        slow = middle;
        if (null == next.next) {
            last = next;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (null == reversed)
        return true;
    boolean mayBePalindrome = last.val == node.val;
    if (mayBePalindrome) {
        last.val = ~node.val; // turn last into sentinel
        // jam "check" and restoration of first half; single comparison
        while (reversed.val == middle.val) {
            ListNode n = reversed.next;
            reversed.next = slow;
            slow = reversed;
            reversed = n;
            middle = middle.next;
        }
        mayBePalindrome &= middle == last;
        last.val = node.val; // restore
    }
    while (null != reversed) {
        ListNode n = reversed.next;
        reversed.next = slow;
        slow = reversed;
        reversed = n;
    }
    return isPalindrome;
}

/** Prints result of isPalindrome() */
static void check(String init) {
    ListNode node = null == init
        ? null : new ListNode(init, null);
    System.out.println("palindrome(" + node
              + "): " + isPalindrome(node));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    check(null);
    check("'");
    check("cc");
    check("codedoc");
    check("codedoC");
    check("cOdedoc");
    check("Maddam");
    check("maddam");
    check("madDam");
}

/** Singly-linked list node class bolstered some to support
 * <code>java.util.List</code> iteration. */
static class ListNode extends java.util.AbstractList<Integer>
    implements List<Integer>
{
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
    ListNode(int x, ListNode n) { val = x; next = n; }
    ListNode(String init, ListNode n) {
        next = n;
        if (null != init && 0 < init.length()) {
            val = init.charAt(0);
            if (1 < init.length())
                next = new ListNode(init.substring(1), n);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Integer get(int index) {
        if (0 == index)
            return val;
        if (index < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("index < 0");
        if (null == next)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("size <= index");
        return next.get(index-1);
    }
    @Override
    public int size() { return null == next ? 1 : 1 + next.size(); }
    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
                ListNode head = ListNode.this;
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() { return null != head; }
                @Override
                public Integer next() {
                    int v = head.val;
                    head = head.next;
                    return v;
                }
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give me this feedback, much appreciated